# How long can I keep rosette-forming Peperomias without pruning, while in ideal growing conditions?

Tags: houseplants, pruning

Unlike nurseries, flower shops do not provide all conditions for healthy growth. Sellers are often stuck with batches of rosette-forming Peperomias such as P. Caperata, P. griseoargentea and P. argyreia. Sellers end-up with poor-looking plants.

What if these plants remained in the nursery under good growing conditions? Will they offset or keep getting taller? remain compact? trail? hang down from the pot? I searched for pictures on how much they grow beyond their sellable size and still look good, but I have found no reference for that.

Answer (score 1):

All of these plants have a maximum height they will reach.  They may not reach this height if they are not getting the best of conditions.  Growing conditions include things like, type of soil, temperature, growing in the ground or in a pot, light, etc...  All of these factors determine the maximum height.   In a greenhouse they way want the plant to only get a certain height.  If that plant tends to grow too tall, then the grower may choose to use a growth inhibitor.  This chemical can often last for months.  Giving the plant a compact look.  If the grower were not to use such a chemical the plant may overfill the pot or get too tall to look clean.

If the growing conditions were perfect but the plant limited by the size of the pot, the pot will cause the plant to dwarf some.  Often growing new leaves that are not as larger as the use to be.  This plant if repotted might take-off with growth again, but still will not pass the maximum height for that plant.   I believe the plants you have list get a maximum of around 12" or 30cm.